# How to assign IDs for consecutive rows in R split by a given kind of row?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe whose rows represent people. For a given family, the first row has the value `1` in the column `A`, and all following rows contain members of the same family until another row in in column `A` has the value `1`. Then, a new family starts.

I would like to assign IDs to all families in my dataset. In other words, I would like to take:

```
A
1
2
3
1
3
3
1
4
```

And turn it into:

```
A    family_id
1    1
2    1
3    1
1    2
3    2
3    2
1    3
4    3
```

I'm playing with a dataframe of 3 million rows, so a simple `for`-loop solution I came up with falls short of necessary efficiency. Also, the `family_id` need not be sequential.

I'll take a dplyr solution.

Comment: `cumsum(df$A == 1)` , In `dplyr`, `df %>%
  mutate(family_id = cumsum(df$A == 1))`

Comment: Thanks. This makes complete sense, though something inconsistent is still going on in my huge sample:

```> df$family_id = cumsum(df$A == 1)
> length(unique(df$family_id))
[1] 2749964
> nrow(df[df$A==1,])
[1] 2892164```

I'll keep trying to figure it out on my end, but let me know if you can catch what might be wrong :).

Comment: Just solved the issue in my comment – it was just a few `NA`s screwing up. @RonakShah if you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, the question has been marked as duplicate. I am glad you did solve it in the end. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

data:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1:3,1,3,3,1,4))
```

code:

```
df$familiy_id <- cumsum(c(-1,diff(df$A)) < 0)
```

result:

```
#  A familiy_id
#1 1          1
#2 2          1
#3 3          1
#4 1          2
#5 3          2
#6 3          2
#7 1          3
#8 4          3
```

---

please note:

This solution starts a new group when a number occurs that is smaller than the previous one.

When its 100% sure that a new group always begins with a `1` consistently, then ronak's solution is perfect.

Comment: The "edge case" you mention in the end does happen :(. Can you think of something to get around it?

Comment: Can you provide an example where my solution fails?